# VBA Sub return output from function

Tags: excel, vba

Hi Guys I am  new to VBA and I am trying to run the code below but I am having difficulties.
When I run the code nothing happens. I do not get an output.

I have three columns: `FT`, `cost` and `weight`.
What I am trying to do is to run an `IF` statement in the column `Ft` to get `ST`, and then to multiply the numbers in the `cost` and `weight` columns which correspond to `st`.
E.g:  Below 7 * 10 then to return the data in the column `O`.

I have saved the data returned by the `IF` statement in array, and then tried to copy them in column `O` but it is not working.  However when I run the function from an Excel cell it works without any issues.

Your help would be much appreciated.

FT

ST

ecommerce

cost

7

5

weight

10

8

```
Public Sub main2()
    Dim ft As Range
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Set ws = Application.ActiveSheet

    Set ft = ws.Range("b2:b365")
    ecco2 = ecco(ft)
End Sub

Function ecco(ft As Range) As Long
    Dim x As Variant
    Dim L As Long
    Dim H As Long
    Dim netarray() As Long

    For Each x In ft
        If ft = "st" Then
            L = x.Offset(0, 1) * x.Offset(0, 3)
        Else
            ecco = 0
        End If

        ecco = L

        ReDim Preserve netarray(L)
        netarray(L) = L + 1
    Next x

    For i = LBound(netarray) To UBound(netarray)
        ActiveSheet.Range("o2").Offset(1, 0).Select
    Next i

End Function
```

Comment: Nowhere in the code do you output anything, so it's not really surprising. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: Please indent your code properly and remove some of the excess whitespace. It will make it easier to read.

Comment: Is the correct sheet `active` when you run the code?

Answer (score 0):

To return data out of a function you need to do this:

```
Private Function ecco (ByRef ft as Range) as Long

    'Insert your logic

    ecco = whatValueAreYouReturning

End Function
```

If you want to set the value of a cell as something, maybe do this in main2:

```
wb.Range("O2").offset(myRowOffset,0).value = ecco(myInput)
'    I reccomend changing ecco() to a function with no loop, and put the loop in main2()
```

Thoughts on the solution:

- If you've done this with a formula, I would reccomend keeping it this way, as they're much easier to maintain.

A few pointers on your code:

- Try to make your variable names longer than "H", because I nor you in a week's time will know what that means when you get back to it
- If you want to set the value of a cell (for example in column O) you can do it like this:

  `ws.Range("O2").Offset(myOffset, 0).value = myValue`

  `ws.Range("O2").Offset(myOffset, 0).Formula= myFormula`

I would fix up the sub and function but I don't actually know where you're going with it, so I'll leave it to you :)